# Button visibility before and after session is called in VB

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, forms

I have two web forms, say a target form and source form. I have two buttons **Save** and **Update** on the target form. What i want these button to do is simply a work with there visibility. I want Save button to be visible when this form is opened but Update button to be invisible. But when this form acts as a target form, i.e., when this form is redirected from another form, I want the save button to be invisible and Update button to be visible. Here is the code that I wrote in target form

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

            update_btn.Visible = False               
            Dim str As String
            Dim i As Integer
            Dim checkData As New DataTable
            str = "select AreaID, Years, StateForest, PrivateForest, TotalForest, PercentageSF, PercentageTotal from forestry_area where AreaID = '" & Session("AreaID").ToString() & "'"
            checkData = c.PopulateData(str, i)
            If i > 0 Then
                ddl_year.SelectedItem.Text = checkData.Rows(0).Item("Years").ToString
                SFtx.Text = checkData.Rows(0).Item("StateForest").ToString
                PFtx.Text = checkData.Rows(0).Item("PrivateForest").ToString
            End If
            txtAreaID.Text = Session("AreaID").ToString()
            update_btn.Visible = True
            save_btn.Visible = False
    End Sub
```

And this is the code that I wrote in source form:

```
Protected Sub Grid_SelectedIndexChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Grid.SelectedIndexChanged

        Dim id As String
        Dim lbl As Label = Grid.SelectedRow.FindControl("Lbl_ID")
        id = lbl.Text
        Session.Add("AreaID", id)
        Response.Redirect("target form.aspx")
    End Sub
```

This code seems to work initially but when I click the update button all the button disappears and Update doesn't even work.

Comment: We need more of your code to know the issue. Post your update btn click code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly your form act as target if `Session("AreaID")` is defined. So you can check this value during `Page_Load` in order to show/hide your buttons.

Please remember that you need to remove session variabile when they became unuseful.

You can also use a parameter in your `Response.Redirect` and verify this parameter instead of a session variable:

```
Response.Redirect("targetform.aspx?areaID=" + id)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it worked with some more alteration at the target form page load. Thanks